# Android: How to Set onClickListener method for component declared inside Start and Stop Drag

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, onclicklistener

```
I made a sample using this link: http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html.
i am able to drag and drop objects from my list view.

Here is the code for my start and stop drag: 


public void onStartDrag(View itemView) {
            itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            defaultBackgroundColor = itemView.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
            // itemView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
            mChangeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_btn);
            Button iv = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
            if (iv != null)
                iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopDrag(View itemView) {
            itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // itemView.setBackgroundColor(defaultBackgroundColor);
            mChangeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_btn);
            Button iv = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
            if (iv != null)
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

My question is how can i set OnClickListener for my Button iv?
Its not allowing me to set on onDrag.
Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the error you get when you try the setonclicklistener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Create a listener object 
2)Create a method which need to define listener
3)Inside drag set listener
This might work :)

```
OnClickListner onclicklistner;
.....
void listner()
{
onclicklistner=new OnclickListner({
void onClick(v.getid){...}
});
}
....
button.setoOnClickListener(onclicklistener);`
```